# Class Not Found? com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory while trying to connect to cloud sql

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to my google cloud sql database, using DriverManager, however am coming across an exception. I have a vauge idea what is wrong just no idea how to fix it.

```
String instanceConnectionName = "x:y:z";
    String databaseName = "dbName";
    String IP_of_instance = "ip";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    String jdbcUrl = String.format(
        "jdbc:mysql://%s/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s"
            + "&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false",IP_of_instance,databaseName,instanceConnectionName);

private void openConnection(){
try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

        // connecting to database
        try{
            // connection string for demos database, username demos, password demos
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch(SQLException se) { System.out.println(se); }    
}
```

It prints the following exception during the second catch, se.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
MESSAGE: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory

STACKTRACE:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:209)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:2189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:282)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2565)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at model.FilmDAO.openConnection(FilmDAO.java:90)
    at model.FilmDAO.getAllFilms(FilmDAO.java:205)
    at controller.allFilms.doGet(allFilms.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

I understand this would indicate that com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory class isnt in my class path, but im still new to this and dont have much understanding to how to add it to my class path.

Comment: _Run configurations..._ item of _Run_ menu in Eclipse. Refer to the [Eclipse] _help_ which is accessible from the _Help_ menu in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the project as a dependency to your `pom.xml`?

It's also generally a bad idea to use Driver Manager directly. I'd suggest taking a look at this [example](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#java), which shows you how to use a connection pool to connect to your instance. The dependencies used can be seen on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet/pom.xml).